# Bad performance (Node.js serving data from MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance-testing, database-performance

I have a MongoDB with small collection of ~100 documents. I want to return all documents ~50KB at once (using Node and Mongoose)

```
Items.find().stream().pipe(JSONStream.stringify(false)).pipe(res);
```

Using ApacheBench with this command

```
ab -r -n 100 -c 10 http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/stress
```

I got this result

```
Document Path:          /api/stress
Document Length:        52866 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   5.738 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      5308266 bytes
HTML transferred:       5286600 bytes
Requests per second:    17.43 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       573.783 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       57.378 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          903.45 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
            min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.3      0       1
Processing:   312  558  95.5    562     853
Waiting:       20  305 118.9    303     527
Total:        312  558  95.6    562     854

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
50%    562
66%    582
75%    605
80%    626
90%    670
95%    715
98%    822
99%    854
100%    854 (longest request)

Document Path:          /api/stress
Document Length:        52866 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   5.738 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      5308266 bytes
HTML transferred:       5286600 bytes
Requests per second:    17.43 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       573.783 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       57.378 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          903.45 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
            min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.3      0       1
Processing:   312  558  95.5    562     853
Waiting:       20  305 118.9    303     527
Total:        312  558  95.6    562     854

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
50%    562
66%    582
75%    605
80%    626
90%    670
95%    715
98%    822
99%    854
100%    854 (longest request)
```

**Requests per second : 17.43 (that seems too little.)**

When returning 10 records

```
Notes.find().limit(10).stream().pipe(JSONStream.stringify(false)).pipe(res);
```

**Requests per second : 146.53 (witch seems good.)**

So I'm wondering, am I interpreting data wrong or am I doing something wrong?, cause I was expecting a bit better performance from returning a bit larger amount of data from MongoDB.

I'm using local Windows machine (i7/8GB) with Node and Mongo localy

Comment: So is the query taking a long time ? The time here is the HTML request  to get processed(get data from mongo + other things the node server does) and return which involves many other components and not only for the mongo query which you are interested in.

Comment: @AlokSwain, query is super fast. It feels like there is some other problem. Could it be the time to convert binary stream to JSON string?

Comment: when I do this
'Notes.find().stream().on('close', function () { res.send('END'); });'
its twice as fast but still slow.

Comment: I don't think there is any conversion happening? I could be wrong but MongoDB stores data in BSON which is just JSON with additional support of more datatypes.

Comment: Have you ever tried to run apache benchmark with -k (Keep-Alive) option?

Answer (score 0):

100 documents for query are returned in 20ms and 10 results are returned in 2ms, then there is some work done by Node, witch in total for 100 rows gives 50ms per request witch gives me 20 requests per second. Not great but I guess I have to deal with It for the moment..